# Capybara iterate over matching elements and click

Tags: loops, click, capybara, match

I wanna iterate over elements on page (add them to cart - 4 items in one spec)

I try with:

`find(".active", match: :first)`

`all(".active").each(&:click)`

but when after test I try to click on link, sometimes it clicked wrong one and my test falling

I use Capybara + Selenium

Comment: Is there a reason you need to go to the first instance of `.active`? Why not just use `all(".active").each(&:click)`?

Comment: match: :first is for Capybara, to wait for that element before click on all, after use only line with :all still can't click next link and  -- all gave me ambigous match (finding all 4) - I can't change app code

Comment: I would say you should find another way to wait for the page to load. Have a look at this: http://makandracards.com/makandra/12139-waiting-for-page-loads-and-ajax-requests-to-finish-with-capybara

Comment: try, but now my test can't even end :)

Comment: I just hard code to visit same page after all, but still need to figure out better solution

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are going to be four items you can do

```
all('.active', count: 4).each &:click
```

which will wait until the 4 .active elements are on the page rather than doing the match: :first call.  This will only work though if the clicks don't remove any of those elements from the page.  It also won't wait for the first click to do whatever it does before doing the second click, not sure whether or not that's an issue for your test without more details of exactly what clicking on the .active elements does

If you really did need the effect of the match: :first call a clearer way to do that would be to do either of the following (rspec or other)

expect(page).to have_selector('.active')

assert_selector('.active')

Comment: after I add them to cart, it generate link with number of them, which I want to catch (like Items in cart (4)), on that I depend that all work ok (I mean adding to cart)

Comment: ok -- but does clicking on the .active element refresh part of the page, or does it load a new page?  If its only refreshing part of the page, does that part of the page include the .active elements, or is it only updating the link with number?